# Image inside a bootstrap container on the right side

Tags: html, css, containers

Here is my problem, I have a container that has row > col > img. But my image should be close to the page border.
This what I have done until now:[image]

The site is responsive, I tried using `margin-right: -n px`, but doesn't work on mobile. 
This is the layout that I want:[image]

Here is my code: https://codepen.io/adrianolopes17/pen/WKGjYo

Any idea? I appreciate it.

Comment: Please provide you code.

Comment: Provide a code. That are a lot of things so you have to pay attention

Comment: I'm guessing the container has padding attached to it, but it would be helpful to have your code

Comment: Here https://codepen.io/adrianolopes17/pen/WKGjYo

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#media-alignment

Answer (score 0):

try adding class "text-md-right" to the image's parent div